# How to read PHP exception in android studio (java)?

Tags: php, android, exception, yii2, android-volley

The API response is PHP exception as below:

```
{
  "name": "Not Found",
  "message": "The record is not found! [0x12]",
  "code": 0,
  "status": 404,
  "type": "yii\\web\\NotFoundHttpException"
}
```

The log in the android studio `E/Volley: [1270] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://localhost/api/v1/friend/mobile/123`

This error trigger by `onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)`, so it's not the respond of the API.

-- UPDATE:
Here is the part to read the JSON:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    //Log.d(SENDMOBILE_TAG, response.toString());
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        int status = response.getInt("status");
                        String message = response.getString("message");
                        if(status == 400) {
                            WebServiceUtils.showDialog(SendMobileActivity.this, "Error" ,message);
                        }else if(status == 201){
                            //WebServiceUtils.showDialog(SendMobileActivity.this, "Success" ,message);
                            Intent SendOtpActivity = new Intent(SendMobileActivity.this, SendOtpActivity.class);
                            startActivity(SendOtpActivity);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Thanks,

Comment: the  response in JSON so you can read  and parse the responsa as a JSON string

Comment: As the first comment says, you can try to parse JSON response. But, as the error message you get, you call to wrong URL. If you want to access localhost from Android Studio Emulator, the address is `10.0.2.2` (not localhost).

Comment: I update my question to show the code.